# Dealing with memory usage due to high element count in Firebase query

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing code that is appending elements from firebase to an array to perform a simple search using a textfield.

The code for the method is below:

```
 var filteredEvents = [Event]()
var eventsArray = [Event]()
fileprivate func fetchEvents(){
    print("Fetching events....")
    //create a reference to the location in the database that you want to pull from and observe the value there
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("events")
    // this will retur a snapshot with all the data at that location in the database and cast the results as a dictionary for later use
    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else{
            return
        }
        //does the job of sorting dictionary elements by key and value
        //displaying the key and each corresponding value
        dictionaries.forEach({ (key,value) in
           // print(key, value)
            //creating an eventDictionary to store the results of previous call
            guard let eventDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else{
                return
            }
            //will cast each of the values as an Event based off my included struct
            //Make sure to create a model it is the only way to have the data in the format you want for easy access
             let events = Event(currentEventKey: key, dictionary:eventDictionary)
            // appends that to the dictionary to create the dictionary of events
            self.eventsArray.append(events)
        })
        // will sort the array elements based off the name
        self.eventsArray.sort(by: { (event1, event2) -> Bool in
            return event1.currentEventName.compare(event2.currentEventName) == .orderedAscending
        })
        // will again reload the data
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()

    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch events for search")
    }
}
```

I personally did not think of the chance where I may have a great number of events. I won't be able to just append all 1000+ events to a dictionary. That will ratchet my memory up. Is there anyway I could have the query respond to the text field. Also could anyone maybe help me with the line for the query that would perform this action but not destroy my memory?

```
"events" : {
"CCDS" : {
  "attend:count" : 1,
  "event:date" : {
    "end:date" : "08/09/2017",
    "end:time" : "7:00 PM",
    "start:date" : "08/09/2017",
    "start:time" : "5:00 PM"
  },
  "event:description" : "Happy hour is more joyful in the summer thanks to Center City District Sips, which offers discounted drinks and appetizers every Wednesday evening.  Catch up with old friends and make a few new ones as Center City’s best bars and restaurants host the summer’s happiest hour every Wednesday from 5-7 p.m.  Enjoy $5 cocktails, $4 wine, $3 beers and half-price appetizers at dozens and dozens of bars and restaurants.",
  "event:imageURL" :someURL",
  "event:location" : {
    "event:city" : "Philadelphia",
    "event:state" : "PA",
    "event:street:address" : "660 Chestnut St",
    "event:zip" : 19106
  },
  "event:name" : "Center City District Sips"
},
"MIA" : {
  "attend:count" : 1,
  "event:date" : {
    "end:date" : "09/03/2017",
    "end:time" : "7:00 PM",
    "start:date" : "09/02/2017",
    "start:time" : "12:00 PM"
  },
  "event:description" : "Budweiser Made in America Festival is an annual music festival held in Philadelphia and formerly simultaneously held in Los Angeles.Sponsored by Anheuser–Busch and produced by Live Nation, the event features several stages that continuously host live music from a wide range of genres including hip hop, rock, pop, R&B, and EDM.",
  "event:imageURL" : "someURL",
  "event:location" : {
    "event:city" : "Philadelphia",
    "event:state" : "PA",
    "event:street:address" : "Ben Franklin Parkway",
    "event:zip" : 19130
  },
  "event:name" : "Made In America"
}
  },
```

For example I want to pull all information about an event that I have searched for using the query. So if I begin to type in Made in America it will pull all relevant information from the events tab about that event

This is what I currently have

```
fileprivate func fetchEvents(searchString: String){
    print("Fetching events....")
    //create a reference to the location in the database that you want to pull from and observe the value there
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("events")
    // this will retur a snapshot with all the data at that location in the database and cast the results as a dictionary for later use
  let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "event:name").queryEqual(toValue: searchString)
    print(query)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else{
            print(snapshot.value)
            return
        }
        print(snapshot.value)
    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch event data", err)
    }

}
```

Returns this

> `(/events { ep = Made In America; i = "event:name"; sp = Made In America; })`

Comment: To clarify, are you asking if there's a way to have a textField where you input some value, and then you query the database looking for that value? Or are you looking to do something like infinite scrolling where a few children are downloaded at a time?

Comment: @JenPerson im looking for a way to have a textfield where I input some value and then quesry the firebase looking for that value

Comment: Notifying every user that has asked/edited your question is not very nice. Please be patient as this is a Q&A community, not a paid support forum. See SO's ["Be Nice" policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: You need to provide more context. Why would you need to download hundreds of objects ? If the user performs a search on the term "house" you'll download a few based on some sort of ranking algo (like every search engine around). In my opinion the solution is to use a page based approach and delete old results when the user queries a new term.

Comment: @nathan what context am I missing. I want to cut down the potential memory issue that my problem will face with multiple users and houses

Comment: @nathan by querying instead of pulling everything than filtering the results

Comment: That's why I recommended pagination. These might guide you to a proper solution: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+%5Bios%5D+pagination

Comment: @nathan Thanks for that link

Comment: If you can post a snippet of your Firebase structure (as TEXT please no images. Firebase Console->Export JSON) and provide and example of what you are searching for, we can help with a [Firebase Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) to get just the data you need.

Comment: @jay thanks, I am sorry I am so late I will do that now

Comment: @Jay see edits Jay

Comment: ...and can you update your question and provide some information about what is being searched for (event name? State? City?) in the text field (per my above comment).

Comment: @Jay updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the question is

```
"How can I query for a value contained in a child node?"
```

Given a structure similar to the original

```
"events" : {
  "CCDS" : {
    "attend:count" : 1,
    "event:imageURL" :"someURL",
    "event:name" : "Center City District Sips"
  "MIA" : {
    "attend:count" : 1,
    "event:imageURL" : "someURL",
    "event:name" : "Made In America"
```

a Firebase query would return the node you want.

If the user typed in *Made In America* and tapped the search button here's the query to return that node in a snapshot.

```
let searchString = "Made In America"
let ref = self.ref.child("events")
let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "event:name").queryEqualTo(searchString)
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let eventDict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
        let attendCount = eventDict["attend:count"] as! String
        let url = eventDict["event:imageURL"} as! String
    }
})
```

If you want to do a partial string match, where the user could type in just a few characters like  *Made* the code is similar but you need to let firebase return all of the matches starting with Made...

The query would look like this

```
let startString = "Made"
let endString = "Made" + "\\uf8ff"
let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "event:name")
                        .queryStarting(atValue: startString)
                        .queryEnding(atValue: endString")
```

The "\uf8ff" is a character at a very high code level in Unicode - because of that it encompasses all of the preceeding characters.

However, querying 'on the fly' can create an unresponsive or sluggish UI so it's not recommended.

An alternative is to create a seperate node that contains a lot less info and contains the elements the user would search for and a reference to the event node.

So the main node containing all the data looks like this

```
"events" : {
  "-uyuh8s8j8jsdas" : {
    "event": "CCDS"
    "attend:count" : 1,
    "event:imageURL" : "someURL",
  "-y88jsijsijjids" : {
    "event": "MIA"
    "attend:count" : 1,
    "event:imageURL" : "someURL",
```

and a 'smaller' node would look like this

```
   events_for_searching
       -uyuh8s8j8jsdas
         event:name: "Center City District Sips"
       -y88jsijsijjids
         event:name: "Made In America"
```

With this, you could load all of the nodes from the events_for_searching into an array (then filter the array as the user types) which would make the UI very responsive and when the user selects a name, you can then use the key from that node as a reference to load the data from the events node via an observeSingleEvent function.

**EDIT**

In response to a comment, I wanted to add a bit more detail in code.

Here's my structure

```
  "events" : {
    "event_0" : {
      "event:name" : "An Event"
    },
    "event_1" : {
      "event:name" : "Made In America"
    }
  },
```

and the code to query for event:name: Made In America

```
let searchString = "Made In America"
let ref = self.ref.child("events")
let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "event:name").queryEqual(toValue: searchString)

query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else{
        print(snapshot.value)
        return
    }
    print(snapshot.value)
}) { (err) in
    print("Failed to fetch event data", err)
}
```

and the output

```
Optional({
    "event_1" =     {
        "event:name" = "Made In America";
    };
})
```

Comment: im not sure what this means
(/events {
    ep = Apples;
    i = "event:name";
    sp = Apples;
})

Comment: @SJackson5 What isn't working and what does your second comment mean? Where does that code or structure appear?

Comment: in the console when i print the result of query

Comment: like when i print snapshot.value to check what it is it never prints

Comment: Hmm. The code in my answer was copy and pasted from a working project so I know it works. I had two suggested options in my answer as well so I don't know which one you implemented. Also, I don't see anything about Apples in your structure so I don't know where that's coming from. I would suggest creating a new question with your new code and be sure to include the Firebase structure that contains Apples.

Comment: well apples is made in america

Comment: i implemented the first one

Comment: sorry about the apples thing

Comment: @SJackson5 Your code works fine. I copy and pasted it into my app, ran it and it printed the Made In America snapshot in the XCode console. If you are not authenticated then it won't print - but that depends on how your rules are set up.

Comment: oh okay ill try it one more time

Comment: @SJackson5 I updated the answer with my Firebase Structure, code and output. I copied and pasted it directly from my project. Remember that firebase is case sensitive so make sure you're matching the case.

Comment: Somewhat versed. Open a well formed question and we'll take a look!

Comment: Can you upvote my question so I can gain enough rep to move our discussion to chat if needed

Comment: I mean to do that! Thanks for the reminder. It's probably better to open a new question if possible so others can benefit.

Comment: very true I will do that