# How can we search through 5,000 users in Firestore db?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js

We have a staffing application, built using vuejs and a firestore database with over 5,000 users. Our challenge is that we need a layout for admins to search for users in the db.

Previously, we were loading all users on our Users.vue layout and then searching/viewing them in a Vuetify data table. The problem now is that we just have too many users. That layout loads way too slowly and will even cause the app to crash on mobile browsers.

The solution we are trying to make work is to search for users in the db, and only load those results into our data table. The code below (using vuex) works, as long as the "name" is EXACT.

```
getUsersState({commit}, payload){
  fb.usersCollection.where("name", "==", payload.search).limit(10).onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
  let usersArray = []
  console.log(payload.search)
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    let user = doc.data()
    user.id = doc.id
    usersArray.push(user)
  })
  commit('setUsers', usersArray)
  })
},
```

The problem is that we need it to work even if we only type in the first few letters of a name or even an email address. Firestore only offers ==, >=, <=, >, and < parameters. And "array-contains" only works with an array, not our "user" object.

On Users.vue:

```
created () {
  console.log('getting users')
  this.$store.dispatch("getUsersState", {search: this.search})
},
computed: {
  ...mapState(['currentUser', 'users', 'userProfile']),
  isAdmin: function() {
    return this.userProfile.accessLevel >= 5
  },
  isUsers: function() {
    return this.users
  }
},
watch: {
  search: 'updateSearch'
},
methods: {
  clearSearch () {
    return this.isSearch = ''
  },
  updateSearch() {
    this.$store.dispatch("getUsersState", {search: this.search})
  },
},
```

Does anyone have any ideas for how we can search the users in our firestore DB by only typing in the first few letters of their name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate a full text search engine, and keep it in sync with Firestore.  Nontrivial to implement.  Official docs recommend Algolia: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search

Comment: Before going an extreme of a full text search, do a search here on SO for [firebase]\uf8ff as those solutions may give you some direction on performing partial string searches in Firebase. Also take a look at my answer here (swift) for a bit more info [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701123/dealing-with-memory-usage-due-to-high-element-count-in-firebase-query/45738986#45738986). It's for Firebase Realtime Database but the concept is similar.

Answer (score 2):

The right answer is full text search, but is a big hammer for this use case.  Here are some other options that can keep you going for a while:

1) First, note that Firestore has an index sitting there that looks like

```
Collection\User\a   -> somedoc
Collection\User\aaa -> somedoc
Collection\User\aba -> somedoc
Collection\User\abc -> somedoc
Collection\User\bbc -> somedoc
```

If you have a username **prefix** like a there is nothing to say you can't run a query for user >='a' and user <= 'b' and have if fetch (in this example) {a,aaa,aba}

Similarly >= 'ab' && <= 'b' gets you {ab, abc}

So you go from fetching all 5000 users to just the users with the prefix -- which is alot smaller.

2) Stuff the things you want to autocomplete into a few documents and load them.

Imagine you have 5000 users, and you store their names into 10 documents with 500 usernames each -- you keep those documents up to date as users add or remove.  To get the *entire* autocomplete list you fetch those 10 documents into the browser and feed the 5000 users to some sort of autocomplete widget. You could do the same thing for emails.

The browser can now do fancy instant autocomplete.  This is faster/cheaper than fetching the entire collection of 5000 users -- you only ask for the data you need.